# Wine Office 2019 Error Code 30175 - 4

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I'm trying to install Office with WineHQ but at 58% office drops a 30175-4 error so I don't know what to do ;-;

[image: Error office]

Comment: Have a look at the answers of https://askubuntu.com/q/1332473/124466 for alternative software.

Comment: but i dont want alternative software! i want MS office