# Does Ubuntu have a MS Office equivalent?

Tags: microsoft-office

Microsoft has multiple apps like Word, Excel and PowerPoint. Google has their versions of them, such as Docs, Sheets and Slides.

I saw there's LibreOffice that's similar to MS Office, but I also wanna know if Ubuntu has their own.

Is there a similar form of MS Office from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is, "No". There is no "Ubuntu" branded Office Suite.

Ubuntu is an operating system (with a graphical desktop environment), like MacOS, Windows, Android, and many others.

[Canonical](https://canonical.com/) has been developing the Ubuntu operating system with the help of community volunteers since 2004. Although Canonical does create other software, they do not offer an Office Suite like MS Office in their portfolio of products.

Just as the Windows operating system can run software from different vendors as long as the software is written to run on Windows, Ubuntu can run software from different vendors as long as the software is written to run on Ubuntu (or an equivalent Linux based operating system).

Some of the software Ubuntu runs is Open Source, which means the code is not secretly guarded, unlike most Microsoft or Apple code which is proprietary.

Of course, Ubuntu can also run proprietary software, and the software may be either free or may costs money to purchase.

The other answer here lists some Open Source and Free (no cost) Office Suites.

I'll add a few more that have Propietary licenses; these have versions you can run on Ubuntu, and they have paid or unpaid versions:

- [ONLYOFFICE Desktop Editors](https://www.onlyoffice.com/desktop.aspx)
- [SoftMaker Office](https://www.softmaker.com/en/softmaker-office)
- [WPS Office](https://www.wps.com/)

Comment: Only office has a FOSS version, with excellent compatibility with MS Office.

Comment: https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors

Answer (score 1):

Open Office & other alternatives exist (each has pros & cons, KDE & Qt systems offer [Caligra Suite](https://calligra.org/)) but LibeOffice is the default for Ubuntu and most *flavors* of Ubuntu

https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/ubuntu-desktop

(even Kubuntu offers LibreOffice; as it's less work on them for their releases; see https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/kubuntu-desktop)

*You didn't mention a release, so I've opted for the latest*

Comment: Wasn't a similar question asked a few weeks ago and published in your Ubuntu newsletter?

Comment: If there was, I don't remember..   the askubu & forum questions are added by script so involve minimal checking ... though https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332473/is-there-any-way-to-use-microsoft-office-in-ubuntu-without-using-wine-or-any-ot maybe what you were thinking of (I did a quick scan)

Comment: That was indeed the one! Thanks.