# PlayOnLinux Excel on Second Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, wine, display, playonlinux

I installed Office with PlayOnLinux/Wine on my Ubuntu 20.04.

The application works fine, but I usually run excel on my second monitor.

When I drag the window, it won't fill the second screen as it fills the main monitor

The left monitor is full filled, but the right one above the excel windows is black.

[image]

Comment: Do office web apps work for you? `sudo snap install office365webdesktop --beta` It should integrate with Ubuntu in a much better way.

Comment: Office Web Apps I can only open files in One Drive. I use Google Drive in my company, so I don't think it will be practical!

Comment: Also, have you tried other alternatives like [ONLYOFFICE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332473/is-there-any-way-to-use-microsoft-office-in-ubuntu-without-using-wine-or-any-ot/1332488#1332488)? I don't know if this issue with Excel can be fixed (Wine sometimes causes weird issues). But someone may be able to offer a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kinda of used your solution.

I installed Office Web Apps

I use inSync already because my Python files can't read native Ubuntu Google Drive well, so I added a OneDrive Account to it. InSync won't sync the same directory to both account (at least didn't find how).

So I made a routine with crontab to execute a command to send files from this folder on Google Drive to OneDrive and OneDrive to Google Drive every 5 minutes.