I tried to install playonLinux on Ubuntu 24.04 but it wasn't able to install office 2013
since on Youtube there're some videos about installing a MS-office 2013 32bit on a Ubuntu, that's why i tried my own, my machine is a Intel i5 10th generation processor with 32 giga RAM , as well as a Nvidia 2060 graphic card, PlayonLinux was successfully installed,it works with a command which was 'sudo apt install python3-pyasyncore', but afterward it doesn't work for install a Office 2013 32 bit, I have download a office 2013 iso file but when i tried to install it , PlayonLinux install a Wine 4.4 even my Ubuntu has a newer version which is 9.x, it just says it encountered a problem and need to send error logs to playonlinux, it can't install a Office 2013 anyway, any idea ? thanks in advanced
ps: my parents sometimes use my computer for documents even they rarely use computer. that's why I need a ms office, it's okay for me to use libreOffice but they are not used to use libreoffice.

Which Ubuntu version are you using, and is it 32-bit or 64-bit?  Also, Office 2013 is pretty old, it might not work with newer Office software versions.

@ThomasWard thank you for replying, my Ubuntu is a 64bit 24.04 system, ppl say office 2013 32 bit is perfectly working on a Ubuntu 20.04, that's why I try use a Office 2013

Have you tried onlyoffice? It is much closer to MS Office compared to LibreOffice, and it is also FOSS https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332473/is-there-any-way-to-use-microsoft-office-in-ubuntu-without-using-wine-or-any-ot/1332488#1332488

Ubuntu 24.04 has PlayonLinux 4.3xx which depends on wine version 9.0. Something is very wrong with your software sources, if you got wine 4.4. ...and the right command to install it is sudo apt install playonlinux

@ArchismanPanigrahi thank you so much

@mikewhatever well thank you for your comment, when i tried to install ms-office, PlayonLinux was trying to install 4.4 itself though, but anyway i have resintalled my Ubuntu 24.04 atm. I am might a brand new way to install ms-office
